# Internet Explorer fails opening a pdf string file

Tags: pdf, base64, internet-explorer-11

I receive (from a webservice I don't manage) a string with the content of a pdf file.

On client's side, I use this function:

window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,'+encodeURI(TheStringWithThePdfContent));

As usual, it works in every browser but IE (11 in my case), which shows an alert with the message: "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer?"

If I say no, an empty white page is opened.

If I say yes, it tries to open a "data" file (as it reads from the protocol in window.open, I guess) and, as it doesn't find any application to do that, sends me to the Microsoft application store, which just suggests me to download "iMusic"

Completely useless, of course.

I've changed all the Internet Options I've guessed could help, none works.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the solution and I want to share anyone who has the same problem. You can see the demo here :
https://jsfiddle.net/quangminh_ln/hy36tnt6/

```
'use strict';

var data = "...Your PDF base64 string...";
var fileName = "your_file_name";
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // IE workaround
    var byteCharacters = atob(data);
    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
}
else { // much easier if not IE
    window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data, '', "height=600,width=800");
}
```

The link that I saw for my solution : https://viethoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/loaddisplay-pdf-from-base64-string-bonus-ie-workaround/

Comment: It does work! 
Finally I changed the server side to change the display of the page, Liferay (where I was receiving and managing the pdf stream) allows to serve a direct pdf page, but it wouldn't have been the case this solution would have been perfect!
I've tested with my own data with different browsers, everything works fine.
Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: This is pure awesomeness :) I would give you +10

Comment: How could I integrate this solution using the following file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-umo7G978pdalJrdVhibHU4Y0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch Could you try to put the content of file PDF "JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2 ..." in the variable data. I hope that it works !

Comment: Would this work for displaying a PDF embedded in a page somehow? Perhaps through an iframe? Embed only works on FF and Chrome as far as I've tried

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This is the only correct answer I could find.

Answer (score -2):

Update Reader or Acrobat

Adobe releases free security updates quarterly. Make sure you update your version of Reader or Acrobat to the latest release. The updates often include fixes to common problems. Download the latest free update.

Open Reader or Acrobat.
Choose Help > Check for Updates.

Acrobat 9 and earlier: If a new update is available it installs automatically.

Acrobat X and XI: Click Update and then click Install.

Acrobat DC: Continue to the next step.
Check for updates
When the Updater dialog box appears, click Download.

Update Acrobat
After download is complete, click the Acrobat install icon. In the Acrobat Updater window, click Install.
Update is Ready
After installation is complete, restart your computer and test the PDF again to see if you can view it.

PDF solutions

Refresh or reload the page

Often, just refreshing the page in your browser allows the PDF to load fully.

Hold down the Shift key and press the   Refresh or   Reload button in the browser.
Try to view a different PDF

Try viewing a different PDF. For example, see if this sample form displays in your browser. If Acrobat or Reader can open the sample form, then the other PDF could be damaged or the web server could be having problems. If possible, contact the individual or company who manages the website.

Try to view a PDF on your hard drive

Determine if your web browser can open a PDF from your local hard drive rather than from the web. For this test, you need a PDF saved on your computer.

In your web browser, do one of the following:

Mac OS: Choose File > Open (or Open File).
Windows: Press Control+O.
Click Browse.

(Windows only) From the Files Of Type menu, choose All Files.
Choose all files
Locate a PDF on your computer, select it, and then click Open.
If the PDF opens, the website you were viewing could have a problem. Contact the individual or company who manages the website.

Comment: What the hex?
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to make a good and clear answer.